# Why was my answer deleted for question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767651/double-insert-in-ms-access

Tags: support, stack-overflow, moderation, deleted-answers

I recently answered question [Double insert in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767651/double-insert-in-ms-access) on SO in a comment to an answer already posted. The question author indicated that I'd helped her out so I should add my comment as an answer to the original question, which she'd then accept.

However, when I copied my comment into new answer against the original question, my answer was deleted...Thanks Jeff :)

I was just wondering why this happened. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was deleted because it didn't look like an answer. Moderators have a lot to do - there was talk of hundreds of flags being in the moderator queue at any given time, so mistakes can happen.  Jeff probably didn't read the exchange in the comments.

Suggestion: Post it again, but worded as an instruction. Like

> Make sure that the aspx:button declaration is not wired up to the onclick event on the code-in-front page as well as the code behind page.

Comment: Not only did he probably not read it, it's unlikely that he ever *saw* it. I understand that the moderators can delete posts from the same interface that displays the flags. They aren't forced to open the page at all to read everything in context. That looks like a "non-answer" to me, so I agree with your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

[lol @ JA.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5934329/revisions)

The "answer" looked 100% like a comment.  We get literally hundreds of flags a day where people post "answers" which are little more than comments.  Almost all of these are from people who don't have enough rep (50) to post an actual comment.

In future, if this happens, you can flag your answer and ask for it to be undeleted.  Just realize that *answers* should look like, smell like, and actually be *answers*.